# Is there any non-naive approach to sliding window algorithm?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sliding-window

I'm trying to extract features out of a 2D rgb image (and later to be extended to 3D depth data).

Basically what I am doing is to slide a 64 x 128 window around my image (and later on, on smaller scale version of the image), with stride of 8x8.
However I find that this approach is really really slow.

Is there any sliding window algorithm that could speed up this process ?

**Edit:** I'm performing detection by extracting HoG features (and its 3d variants) from the sliding window, before using SVM to predict the result.

Comment: Depending on what processing you do in your window, and what kind of features you want to detect, theer might be different speed up strategies. Could you please expand your problem description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the sliding window only for detection of the object, then this [paper](https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/34843.pdf) is quite a good reference for a branch and bound approach with scale invariance.

Comment: "the best paper prize at CVPR 2008", [pdf](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/publications/pdfs/pdf5070.pdf)

Comment: @Cfr Is it same file with one shared on the answer? Because the link hasn't worked any more.